# Is there a technical reason why you might use a two inverting amplifiers instead of a single non-inverting amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier

For example, I found a schematic that uses two inverting opamps to amplify the output of an [AD590](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD590.pdf) with a gain of 1000:

[image: Schematic]

In this case the second opamp appears to be doing nothing but "re-inverting" the amplified voltage as it has a gain of 1. Perhaps this has something specifically to do with the AD590, or the opamp itself (the [LT1014](https://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/10134fd.pdf)), or perhaps it's just to use up an otherwise unneeded fourth opamp in a quad package?

Is it be a safe assumption that it would be possible to replace these two opamps with a single non-inverting opamp with a gain of 1000?

Edit: After probing around (and just looking at the bands on the resistors) it appears that R28 is in fact a 10kΩ resistor.

Comment: One reason would be to get a unity gain.

Comment: There is a distinct difference. The 2nd stage is setup with a 2K resistor to control the source impedance.

Comment: Due to negative feedback the source impedance will be 2k/0.5*Aol with Aol=open-loop gain. Hence, I ask myself: What is the purpose of the 2k resistor?

Comment: @MichaelKaras Could this not be achieved with a non-inverting amplifier?

Comment: In the "good old days" when op amps  choices  were not great  (709,741 etc.) building an audio amp with a gain of 100 meant the high frequency response was severely cut off due to poor gain-bandwidth product. To help overcome this two 10X amps were cascaded. Not quite the situation here but a valid technical reason for having the two amps rather than just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply ground the left end of R30 and connect the AD590 to the non-inverting input of the op-amp. That would actually be better- right now R27 is stupid- it should be 100K to match the bias currents, but with the aforementioned connection scheme it would be the correct value**. The AD590 will 'see' exactly the same voltage across it.

If you want to add R24 in series with the op-amp output it would maintain the current limiting. Note that a capacitive load in either case will tend to destabilize the amplifier, but it's worse in the circuit as shown because the closed-loop gain is lower.

As to why they used this- I can only assume they felt some need to use up the amplifiers in a quad package. A better way to do that would be to connect output to inverting input and ground the non-inverting input.

There are applications where it is better to use two inverting amplifiers rather than one non-inverting, but this isn't one.

** note that R27 may be intended to have a resistor connected between the non-inverting input and a reference voltage to bias the output closer to 0V at 0°C. As shown it will be saturated at room temperature even at the maximum supply voltage of the chip (+/-22V).

Comment: So, something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NnCOA.png)? Also, are 100Ω/10kΩ optimal in this situation? Or would 1kΩ/100kΩ or 10kΩ/1MΩ be more reasonable?

Comment: That has a gain of 101 so the output would be about 3V at room temperature. The 100\$\Omega\$/10K\$\Omega\$ is good. Note the gain is 1% higher than the original should have been.

Answer (score 2):

The AD590 has a CURRENT output. For this reason, you must use an opamp wired as an (inverting) current-to-voltage converter - and you cannot (directly) feed a current into the noninverting input terminal of an opamp.

The mentioned gain of 1000 is a voltage gain (but your input signal is a current). Hence, in case of an ideal current source the input current I goes through the feedback resistor and produces a an output voltage of
 **Vout=-I*R28**.

If your question is a general one - independent on the shown example circuit, the answer is as follows: There are many cases where an inverting amplifier is required - for example as active devices in active filter circuits, harmonic oscillator circuits or as a controller block in control loops.

Comment: Your math doesn't seem to make sense, at 5V and +25°C the AD590 Iout should be 298µA meaning Vout = -(2.98E-4V) * 100kΩ = -29.8V which would pretty much always leave the output voltage hammered at the -15V rail

Comment: @DavidFreitag Agreed, yet LvW's math is correct.

Comment: @DavidFreitag, it is not my math - it is just circuit theory. If the circuit will function as desired is another question (I did not comment on).

Comment: @LvW The issue is that I know the circuit works, but given the available information I cannot reconcile how. I guess I've got some probing to do.

Comment: @DavidFreitag - That's a bad circuit design. R28 is almost certainly a 10k resistor, and it would be a rather old op amp to need either R26 or R27. Is there any chance you could provide a link in the OP to the schematic?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Yes it appears you are correct, I should have started with probing (doh!). This means Vout = -2.98V at 25°C which makes much more sense.